# (discord.py) How to send content of a text file as a message

Tags: python, discord.py

I want my bot to send ascii art. The art is contained in a text file because it's more organized, but when i try to make the bot send it it just sends the file download. I am currently using `await ctx.send(file=discord.File('file path'))`. How do i convert the contents of the file to a string that can be sent as a message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open the txt file read its content and send it

```py
with open("filename.txt") as f:
    content = "\n".join(f.readlines())

await ctx.send(content)
```